# DatagridView concat strings

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a datagridview with a column "name".
There are about 50 rows with names. I would like to get all the names in one delimited sting, like this "David, john, Kim".
Do I have to loop on all the rows in the grid for this or there is something cleaner without looping?

I'm using framework 4.0, c# winforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with help of LINQ:

```
string names = string.Join(", ", grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
               .Select(i => i.Cells["name"].Value.ToString()).ToArray())
```